# What are the inclusion arrows in the coproducts of the category of algebras for a monad?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, proof-explanation, limits-colimits, monads

$\newcommand{\A}{\mathscr{A}}\newcommand{\C}{\mathsf{C}}\newcommand{\T}{\mathcal{T}}\newcommand{\id}{\operatorname{id}}$Riehl, proposition $5.6.11$, from [Category Theory in Context](https://people.math.rochester.edu/faculty/doug/otherpapers/Riehl-CTC.pdf):

> Suppose $\C$ is a cocomplete category and $\A$ is a category with all coequalisers. If $\A$ is monadic over $\C$, then $\A$ is cocomplete.

The proof is mostly left as an exercise. If you are unfamiliar with the notation used, I explain it in the second section. There is a very similar [nLab article](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/colimits+in+categories+of+algebras#reflexive_coequalizers_and_cocompleteness) that is equally brief. I'll paraphrase her sketch:

> By cocontinuity of equivalences, we can replace $\A$ by the category $\C^\T$ where $\T$ is the relevant monad, and $\C^\T$ must have all coequalisers.
>
> Let $(A_i,\alpha_i)_{i\in I}\in\C^\T$ be any given family of algebras. The coproduct $(A,\alpha)$ of this family is defined to be the coequaliser at the right of the following diagram:

[image: Coequaliser diagram]

> All objects in the fork are free $\T$-algebras. Using the adjunction $U^\T\vdash F^\T$ it is straightforward to show $(A,\alpha)$ is a coproduct. Then $\C^\T$ has all coproducts and coequalisers, thus all colimits.

Here, I assume $\kappa:\bigsqcup_i\T(A_i)\to \T(\bigsqcup_i A_i)$ is the unique arrow induced by the arrows $\T(j):\T(A_j)\to\T(\bigsqcup_i A_i)$, $j:A_j\hookrightarrow\bigsqcup_iA_i$ being the coproduct inclusion.

The trouble is, I can't make out what the inclusions arrows $(A_i,\alpha_i)\hookrightarrow (A,\alpha)$ are supposed to be! The nLab article says that it is not difficult to show $A=\bigsqcup_i A_i$, but what should $\alpha$ be? If we can construct this coequaliser by hand anyway, what's the point of assuming coequalisers exist? It just doesn't make sense to me.

My thoughts:

$(A,\alpha)$ is created as a coequaliser. We know nothing about it other than this, so to get an arrow $(A_j,\alpha_j)\to(A,\alpha)$ I have to route it through any of the objects in the coequaliser fork, almost certainly the free algebra $F^\T(\bigsqcup_i A_i)$. However, finding arrows *into* $F^\T$ is hard, since it is the *left* adjoint.

I need to find some arrow $\iota_j:A_j\to\T(\bigsqcup_i A_i)$ for every $j$ and: (i) hope $\iota_j$ lifts to an algebra homomorphism, (ii) hope that it is the right choice of inclusion arrow for the coproduct universal property. There is only one 'natural' choice of $\iota_j$ that I can see: $$\large\left(A_j\overset{j}{\hookrightarrow}\bigsqcup_i A_i\overset{\eta_{\sqcup_i A_i}}{\longrightarrow}\T\left(\bigsqcup_i A_i\right)\right)=\left( A_j\overset{\eta_{A_j}}{\longrightarrow}\T(A_j)\overset{\T(j)}{\longrightarrow}\T\left(\bigsqcup_i A_i\right)\right)$$

But unfortunately this isn’t necessarily a homomorphism. If this $\iota_j$ satisfies $\iota_j\alpha_j=\mu_{\sqcup_i A_i}\T(\iota_j)$, then that is iff: $$\begin{align}\T(j)\eta_{A_j}\alpha_j&=\mu_{\sqcup_i A_i}\T^2(j)\T(\eta_{A_j})\\&=\T(j)\mu_{A_j}\T(\eta_{A_j})\\&=\T(j)\end{align}$$Though $\alpha_j\eta_{A_j}=\id_j$, $\eta_{A_j}\alpha_j\neq\id_{\T(A_j)}$ in general. So this map isn't, as far as I can tell, guaranteed to be a homomorphism. There are also no other 'natural' choices, I think, for these inclusions - so I am stuck. By ‘natural’ I really mean to say: there just aren’t any other maps we can guarantee to exist, that I can think of.

I would really appreciate a concrete description of what the inclusion homomorphisms $(A_j,\alpha_j)\to(A,\alpha)$ are, and any hints / answers for showing $(A,\alpha)$ is indeed a coproduct would be most welcome.

Another point: as a left adjoint, $F^\T$ preserves all colimits, and $\C$ is cocomplete. Perhaps that is necessary here... but so far, Riehl has only suggested that we require $\C$ to have all coproducts - I'm not sure why $\C$ needs to have all colimits.

---

In case Riehl's notation isn't well-known, here is the definition of $\C^\T$:

> For a monad $(\T,\eta,\mu)$ on a category $\C$, we define the Eilenberg-Moore category, a.k.a. category of $\T$-algebras, $\C^\T$ to have objects pairs $(c,\varsigma)$ where $c\in\C$ and $\varsigma:\T\C\to\C$ is some arrow in $\C$, the 'algebra structure map', which must satisfy the two conditions: $$\varsigma\eta_c=\id_c,\quad\varsigma\mu_c=\varsigma\T(\varsigma)$$Arrows in $\C^\T$ shall be "$\T$-algebra homomorphisms" $f:(c,\varsigma)\to(c',\varsigma')$ corresponding to arrows $f:c\to c'$ in $\C$ that satisfy the condition: $$f\varsigma=\varsigma'\T(f)$$The identity arrows and arrow composition are inherited from $\C$.
>
> The adjunction she refers to is this: $F^\T:\C\to\C^\T$ is the functor assigning $c\mapsto(\T c;\mu_c)$ and $f:c\to c'$ is mapped to $\T(f)$ ($F^\T$ creates 'free algebras' and 'free maps'). $U^\T:\C^\T\to\C$ is the forgetful functor.

Comment: I apologise for bumping this post so many times. I just wanted to clean up the formatting and also provide, for posterity, the easier solution. It turns out Riehl and nLab were justified in finding this obvious, if I had just thought a little bit more categorically I would have avoided the more difficult, concrete computations of my answer $7$ months ago. It would be nice to have a feature where you can edit the post without bumping it in the "active questions" queue, this post is well-answered and no longer active...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\A}{\mathscr{A}}\newcommand{\C}{\mathsf{C}}\newcommand{\T}{\mathcal{T}}\newcommand{\id}{\operatorname{id}}$EDIT: About half a year later. There is indeed an easier proof available, that I worked out yesterday, after I was reminded of this post. Also, I realised my answer was slightly obscure (I got myself confused re-reading it yesterday, which is what prompted me to find the easier solution) so I would like to explain the notations a bit.

I'll just write the easier method now, really the rest is waffle but I think it was worth saying.

We should note that the unit $\eta$ for the adjunction $F^\T\dashv U^\T$ is the same as the unit $\eta$ for $\T$ (thankfully no conflict of notation!) and for any algebra $(c,\varsigma)$, the counit $\varepsilon_c$ will be $\mu_c:F^\T U^\T(c,\varsigma)=F^\T(c)\to(c,\varsigma)$.

---

Fix a family of algebras $(X_i,\xi_i)_{i\in I}$. I use $\overline{f}$ to denote the transpose of the arrow $f$ under the adjunction $F^\T\dashv U^\T$ and use standard identities to compute such transposes.

Families of algebra homomorphisms $(\varphi_j:(X_j,\xi_j)\to(c,\varsigma))_{j\in I}$

$\cong$

Families of arrows (in $\C$) $(\varphi_j:U^\T(X_j,\xi_j)\to U^\T(c,\varsigma))_{j\in I}$ satisfying: $$\varphi_j\circ U^\T(\varepsilon_{(X_j,\xi_j)})\equiv U^\T(\overline{\varphi_j})$$In $j\in I$.

$\cong$

Families of algebra homomorphisms $(\psi_j:F^\T U^\T(X_j,\xi_j)\to(c,\varsigma))_{j\in I}$ satisfying: $$\overline{\psi_j}\circ U^\T(\varepsilon_{(X_j,\xi_j)})\equiv U^\T(\psi_j)\\\iff\\\psi_j\circ F^\T U^\T(\varepsilon_{(X_j,\xi_j)})\equiv\psi_j\circ\varepsilon_{F^\T U^\T(X_j,\xi_j)}$$In $j\in I$

$\cong$

Algebra homomorphisms $\varphi:(X,\xi)\to(c,\varsigma)$ where $(X,\xi)$ is defined to be the coequaliser of the algebra homomorphisms $\sum_i\T(\xi_i)$ and $\sum_i\mu_{X_i}$ from: $$\sum_iF^\T U^\T F^\T U^\T(X_i,\xi_i)=\sum_i(\T^2X_i,\mu_{\T X_i})\to\sum_i(\T X_i,\mu_{X_i})=\sum_iF^\T U^\T(X_i,\xi_i)$$

Therefore, $(X,\xi)$ is a valid coproduct for the algebras $(X_i,\xi_i)_{i\in I}$. Stepping backwards through this proof with $\varphi:=\mathrm{Id}$ would find the inclusion homomorphisms $\varphi_j$ to be exactly $p\circ j'\circ\eta_{X_j}$, as equivalently stated by my older answer. This proof is nicer in that one hardly needs to think to find these inclusions, whereas half a year ago I was playing guessing games.

---

The below answer is absolutely correct, and a nice concrete calculation, but I would like to clarify it. I write things like $\sum_i(-)$ (of algebras), but one should be wary of using symbols that are not yet really defined. The whole point is that we *don't* have coproducts (yet!) available to use. So whenever you read something like $\sum_i(\T X_i,\mu_{X_i})$, we must read it as a more convenient notation for: $F^\T(\sum_i X_i)$. The two are literally equal, not just isomorphic, nice I have no other way (*a priori*) to construct coproducts.

On that note, stepping through the proof for why left adjoints preserve colimits, we can directly compute that: $$\sum_i\T\xi_i:\sum_i(\T^2X_i,\mu_{\T X_i})\to\sum_i(\T X_i,\mu_{X_i})$$Equals: $$\T\left(\sum_i\xi_i\right):F^\T\left(\sum_i\T X_i\right)\to F^\T\left(\sum_i X_i\right)$$And that: $$\sum_i\mu_{X_i}:\sum_i(\T^2X_i,\mu_{\T X_i})\to\sum_i(\T X_i,\mu_{X_i})$$Equals: $$\mu_{\sum_i X_i}\circ\T(\kappa):F^\T\left(\sum_i\T X_i\right)\to F^\T\left(\sum_i X_i\right)$$Where $\kappa$ is, as I originally suspected, the unique arrow $\sum_i\T X_i\to\T\left(\sum_i X_i\right)$ induced by the components $\T(j):\T X_j\to\T\left(\sum_i X_i\right)$.

I won't go into details, but you can verify these equalities by using the following (which I arrived at by stepping through the reason why left adjoints preserve colimits):

> Given a family of objects $(c_i)_{i\in I}$ of $\C$, $F^\T\left(\sum_i c_i\right)$ functions as a coproduct of the free algebras $(F^\T(c_i))_{i\in I}$ in the following way - it has for its inclusions the homomorphisms $\T(j)=F^\T(j):F^\T(c_j)\to F^\T\left(\sum_i c_i\right)$ where $j:c_j\hookrightarrow\sum_i c_i$ is the inclusion (in $\C$) and:
>
> > Families of algebra homomorphisms $$\varphi_i:F^\T(X_i)\to(A,\alpha)$$Create a unique algebra homomorphism: $$\varphi:F^\T\left(\sum_i c_i\right)\to(A,\alpha)$$Satisfying $\varphi\circ\T(j)=\varphi_j$ for all $j\in I$, by computing: $$\varphi:=\alpha\circ\T(\langle\varphi_i\eta_{c_i}\rangle_{i\in I})$$

So the diagram used below to construct the coproduct is "exactly the same" as the one proposed by Riehl in the sense that, if $F^\T$ is used to construct coproducts of free algebras, then we get the above equalities.

---

Original self-answer:

---

A less opaque exposition is given [here](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/REU2019/REUPapers/Hermelink.pdf) but it still omits some details that caused me a headache or two... A key point is my last observation that $F^\T$ preserves colimits. I will explain their exposition here for posterity and also for my own note-taking.

In their notation, we consider a family $(X_i,\xi_i)_{i\in I}$ of algebras. We know that $\sum_i X_i$ exists in $\C$, and that: $$\left(\T\left(\sum_i X_i\right),\mu_{\sum_i X_i}\right)=F^\T\left(\sum_i X_i\right)\cong\sum_i(\T X_i,\mu_{X_i})$$Define the inclusions $j:X_j\to\sum_i X_j$, $j':(\T X_j,\mu_{X_j})\to\sum_i(\T X_i,\mu_{X_i})$, $j'':(\T^2 X_j,\mu_{\T X_j})\to\sum_i(\T^2 X_i,\mu_{\T X_i})$. We know that $T(j)$ corresponds to $j'$ under the isomorphism. This is because $F^\T$ is cocontinuous!

Now, we define an algebra $(X,\xi)$ by the coequaliser: $$\sum_i(\T^2 X_i,\mu_{\T X_i})\overset{\sum_i\mu_{X_i}}{\underset{\sum_i\T\xi_i}{\large\rightrightarrows}}\sum_i(\T X_i,\mu_{X_i})\cong\left(\T\left(\sum_i X_i\right),\mu_{\sum_i X_i}\right)\overset{p}\longrightarrow(X,\xi)$$

*We define the inclusions as follows:*

> Set $h_j=p\circ\eta_{\sum_i X_i}\circ j:X_j\to X$. This is an algebra homomorphism **because $p$ is** (my oversight before was to not try to show $h_j$ a homomorphism directly, but to attempt to show each component is a homomorphism - which is false): $$\begin{align}\xi\circ\T(h_j)&=\xi\circ\T(p)\circ\T(\eta_{\sum_i X_i})\circ\T(j)\\&=p\circ\mu_{\sum_i X_i}\circ\T(\eta_{\sum_i X_i})\circ\T(j)\\&=p\circ\T(j)\\h_j\circ\xi_j&=p\circ\T(j)\circ\T(\xi_j)\circ\eta_{\T X_j}\\&=p\circ\T(j)\circ\mu_{X_i}\circ\eta_{\T X_j}\\&=p\circ\T(j)\end{align}$$Where the fact that $p$ is a homomorphism is used, but also that $p$ commutes with the parallel coproduct arrows $\sum_i\mu_{X_i},\,\sum_i\T(\xi_i)$.

So that settles my original question.

Now suppose $(\sigma,\varsigma)$ is some other $\T$-algebra with given homomorphisms $c_i:(X_i,\xi_i)\to(\sigma,\varsigma)$. Then $c_i\xi_i:(\T X_i,\mu_{X_i})\to(\sigma,\varsigma)$ are homomorphisms, inducing a unique homomorphism: $$g:\left(\T\left(\sum_i X_i\right),\mu_{\sum_i X_i}\right)\to(\sigma,\varsigma)$$For which $g\circ\T(j)=c_j\circ\xi_j$ for all $j\in I$. Then: $$\sum_i(\T^2 X_i,\mu_{\T X_i})\overset{\sum_i\mu_{X_i}}{\underset{\sum_i\T\xi_i}{\large\rightrightarrows}}\sum_i(\T X_i,\mu_{X_i})\cong\left(\T\left(\sum_i X_i\right),\mu_{\sum_i X_i}\right)\overset{g}\longrightarrow(\sigma,\varsigma)$$Commutes; it is equivalent to check commutativity on every coordinate. Precomposing with an inclusion $j''$ gives $g\T(j)\mu_{X_j}$ versus $g\T(j)\T(\xi_j)$, that is, $c_j\circ\xi_j\circ\mu_{X_j}$ versus $c_j\circ\xi_j\circ\T(\xi_j)$. But: $\xi_j\mu_{X_j}=\xi_j\T(\xi_j)$ holds by definition of an algebra structure map $\xi_j$, so indeed the above fork commutes.

Thus $g=c\circ p$ for a unique homomorphism $c:(X,\xi)\to(\sigma,\varsigma)$. We can compute: $$\begin{align}c\circ h_j&=c\circ p\circ\eta_{\sum_i X_i}\circ j\\&=g\circ\T(j)\circ\eta_{X_j}\\&=c_j\circ\xi_j\circ\eta_{X_j}\\&=c_j\end{align}$$As desired. Moreover, if $\zeta:(X,\xi)\to(\sigma,\varsigma)$ is any other homomorphism with the property $\zeta\circ h_j=c_j$ for all $j\in I$, then: $$\zeta\circ p\circ\eta_{\sum_i X_i}\circ j\equiv g\circ\eta_{\sum_i X_i}\circ j,\,\forall j\in I$$Implies by the uniqueness of the coproduct arrow that: $$\zeta\circ p\circ\eta_{\sum_i X_i}=g\circ\eta_{\sum_i X_i}$$Then we use the fact that $\zeta,g$ and $p$ are all homomorphisms to get: $$\begin{align}g&=g\circ\mu_{\sum_i X_i}\circ\T(\eta_{\sum_i X_i})\\&=\varsigma\circ\T(g\circ\eta_{\sum_i X_i})\\&=\varsigma\circ\T(\zeta)\circ \T(p)\circ\T(\eta_{\sum_i X_i})\\&=\zeta\circ\xi\circ\T(p)\circ\T(\eta_{\sum_i X_i})\\&=\zeta\circ p\circ\mu_{\sum_i X_i}\circ\T(\eta_{\sum_i X_i})\\&=\zeta\circ p\end{align}$$But $g=\zeta\circ p$ implies $\zeta=c$ by uniqueness! Therefore, $c$ is the unique homomorphism with the property $c\circ h_j=c_j$ for all $j$.

That concludes $(X,\xi)$ is indeed a coproduct for $(X_i,\xi_i)_{i\in I}$.

Comment: I wonder why Riehl left this as an exercise. It doesn't seem that straightforward (at least after the traces of your struggle). Thank you very much for all the insight!

Comment: @ElíasGuisadoVillalgordo My old answer makes it look harder than it perhaps needed to be, but I still include it as an example of an explicit computation (which are rarely given in category theory). The "quick" way using just abstract perspectives is not so bad, I expect that's what Riehl had in mind. Still not easy though. But thanks for visiting this old ramble! It is reassuring, that my self-answers are not solely benefitting myself

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be helpful to think of a special case, but still one which has all the essential features of the general case.  In a rare occurrence, for this construction the category of $M$-sets for a monoid $M$ is not sufficient for this purpose, since coproducts of $M$-sets are formed on disjoint unions of the underlying sets.  So, let us go one step up and consider the category of monoids, which are the algebras for the $\mathsf{list}$ monad.  For clarity, I will also restrict to the case of a coproduct of two objects.

So, now recall that a standard way to form a coproduct of two monoids $M$ and $N$ is to form lists of elements of $M$ or $N$, modulo the equivalence generated by removing $e_M$ or $e_N$, or combining two adjacent elements from the same monoid by taking their product.  Now, the monadic point of view encourages us to consider combinations of multiple such reductions at once.  What we can come up with is: group a list of elements of $M \sqcup N$ into sublists in which each sublist is only from one of $M$ or $N$, and then take the product of each sublist.  In this, a grouping is an element of $\mathsf{list}(\mathsf{list}(M) \sqcup \mathsf{list}(N))$.  (Letting one of the sublists be empty will let us introduce $e_M$ or $e_N$ freely; so it's the opposite direction of the "reduction" we might have expected, but it still works for our purposes.)  Forgetting the grouping corresponds to composing $\mathsf{list}(\mathsf{list}(\iota_M) + \mathsf{list}(\iota_N))$ to get an element of $\mathsf{list}(\mathsf{list}(M \sqcup N))$, and then $\mu$ to get an element of $\mathsf{list}(M \sqcup N)$.  On the other hand, taking the product of each sublist corresponds to $\mathsf{list}(\alpha_M \sqcup \alpha_N)$.  We thus get the standard coproduct $M * N$ as the coequalizer of these two maps.

In terms of this construction, let us go through the questions that need to be answered to show this does give a coproduct.  I'll leave it as an exercise to translate these to the general case from the question, which should be straightforward.

- *What is the monoid structure on $M*N$?*  This would be the map induced by $\mu_{\mathsf{list}(M)\sqcup \mathsf{list}(N))}$, where we need to check well-definedness.  This argument is probably difficult to generalize, so it is replaced by the assumption that $\mathscr{A}$ has coequalizers, and observing that the given morphisms in the coequalizer are algebra homomorphisms.
- *What are the canonical maps $M \to M*N$ and $N \to M*N$?*  Focusing on the first, we take $m \in M$ to the image of the list $[\iota_M(m)] \in \operatorname{list}(M\sqcup N)$, which is just $\eta_{\mathsf{list}(M\sqcup N)}(\iota_M(m))$.
- *Why are these maps monoid homomorphisms?*  Well, here is where the coequalizer comes in.  Given a list $[m_1, \ldots, m_k] \in \mathsf{list}(M)$, we can consider them in a single grouping $[[\iota_M(m_1), \ldots, \iota_M(m_k)]]$.  Forgetting the grouping gives $[\iota_M(m_1), \ldots, \iota_M(m_k)]$ whereas taking the product of each sublist gives $[\iota_M(m_1 \cdots m_k)]$.  Therefore, in $M*N$, we have $[\iota_M(m_1), \ldots, \iota_M(m_k)]$ equivalent to $[\iota_M(m_1 \cdots m_k)]$ which shows the required (monadic version of the) monoid homomorphism condition.
- *Why is $M*N$ with the given morphisms from $M$ and $N$ the coproduct?*  So, let us suppose we have module homomorphisms $f : M\to P$ and $g : N \to P$.  Then the natural way to construct a map $M*N \to P$ would be by starting with an element of $\mathsf{list}(M\sqcup N)$ and applying $\mathsf{list}(f + g)$ to get an element of $\mathsf{list}(P)$, and then applying the product operation $\alpha_P$ to get an element of $P$.  We then need to check this induces a well-defined map $M*N \to P$, and that it gives a monoid homomorphism.  To show the uniqueness of this morphism, we can use the observation that an element of $\mathsf{list}(M\sqcup N)$, $[x_1, \ldots, x_k]$, can be written as the product of $[[x_1], \ldots, [x_k]]$, and the image of each $[x_i]$ is uniquely determined by $f$ and $g$.

Comment: I've formally verified the claim twice now, but will read over this example in the morning in the hopes of learning some intuition.

Comment: What's the difference between "$+$" and "$\sqcup$"? To me, $\iota_M\sqcup\iota_N$ and $\iota_M+\iota_N$ denote the same thing

Comment: To me, for $f : A \to C$ and $g : B \to C$, $f+g$ is the combination $A+B \to C$ from the universal property.  Whereas for $f : A \to C$ and $g : B \to D$, $f \sqcup g$ is the map $A\sqcup B \to C\sqcup D$.  So $f \sqcup g = (\iota_C \circ f) + (\iota_D \circ g)$.

Comment: Ok. Well, thanks for the example +1 It’s always good to have a concrete computation to refer to

Answer (score 0):

One approach to such problems is to establish more broadly a natural bijection of cocones with vertex $(A,\alpha)$ under the diagram consisting of the parallel morphisms $T\bigsqcup_i\alpha_i$ and $\mu_{\bigsqcup_i A_i}\circ T\kappa$, and cocones with vertex $(A,\alpha)$ under the discrete diagram of objects $(A_i,\alpha_i)$. Given such a natural bijection, the colimits of the diagrams would have to correspond, whence the coequalizer and coproduct would. In particular, such a natural bijection would explicitly describe how to go back and forth between components of the cocone under the parallel morphisms and components of the cocone under the discrete diagram.

---

A cocone with vertex $(A,\alpha)$ under $(A_i,\alpha_i)$ in the category of $T$-algebras is given by a cocone with vertex $A$ and components $f_i\colon A\to A_i$ that are $T$-algebra homomorphisms, i.e. satisfying $f_i\circ\alpha_i=\alpha\circ f_i$.

Let $j_i\colon A_i\to\bigsqcup_i A_i$ be inclusions of a coproduct, i.e.a universal cocone. Then by definition cocones $f_i\colon A_i\to A$ correspond bijectively to morphisms $f\colon\bigsqcup_i A_i\to A$ such that $f\circ j_i=f_i$. Moreover, the universal property of the unit $\eta_{\bigsqcup_i A_i}\to T\bigsqcup_i A_i$ asserts that morphisms $f\colon\bigsqcup_i A_i\to A$ correspond bijectively to morphisms of $T$-algebras $\phi\colon T\bigsqcup_i A_i\to A$ from $(T\bigsqcup_i A_i,\mu_{T\bigsqcup_i A_i})$ to $(A,\alpha)$ such that $\phi\circ\eta_{\bigsqcup_i A_i}=f$.

The condition $f_i\circ\alpha_i=\alpha\circ Tf_i$ that the cocone $f_i\colon A_i\to A$ consits of $T$-algebra homomorphisms from $(A_i,\alpha_i)$ to $(A,\alpha)$ can be expressed in terms of the corresponding $T$-algebra homomorphisms $\phi\colon T\bigsqcup_iA_i\to A$ as $\phi\circ\eta_{\bigsqcup_iA_i}\circ j_i\circ\alpha_i=\alpha\circ T\phi\circ T\eta_{\bigsqcup_iA_i}\circ Tj_i$.

To simplify the conditions, let $k_i\colon TA_i\to\bigsqcup_i TA_i$ be coproduct inclusions. Then by definition $\bigsqcup_i\alpha_i\colon\bigsqcup_iTA_i\to\bigsqcup_iA_i$ satisfies $j_i\circ\alpha_i=\bigsqcup_i\alpha_i\circ k_i$. Moreover, $\eta_{\bigsqcup_i A_i}\circ\bigsqcup_i\alpha_i=T\bigsqcup_i\alpha_i\circ\eta_{\bigsqcup_i TA_i}$ by naturality of the unit of the monad. Thus the left-hand side simplifies to $\phi\circ\bigsqcup_i\alpha_i\circ\eta_{\bigsqcup_iTA_i}\circ k_i$.

Next, $\eta_{\bigsqcup_i A_i}\circ j_i=Tj_i\circ\eta_{A_i}$ by the naturality of the unit. Moreover, $Tj_i\colon TA_i\to T\bigsqcup_iA_i$ factor as $Tj_i=\kappa\circ k_i$ for a unique $\kappa\colon\bigsqcup_i TA_i\to T\bigsqcup_iA_i$. Since $\phi\colon T\bigsqcup_iA_i\to A$ is a $T$-algebra homomorphism from $(T\bigsqcup_iA_i,\mu_{\bigsqcup_iA_i})$ to $(A,\alpha)$, we also have $\alpha\circ T\phi=\phi\circ\mu_{\bigsqcup_iA_i}$.
Finally, the unit of the monad being a unit for its multiplication gives $\mu_{\bigsqcup_iA_i}\circ T\eta_{\bigsqcup_iA_i}=\mu_{\bigsqcup_iA_i}\circ\eta_{T\bigsqcup_iA_i}$, and naturality of the unit then yields $\eta_{T\bigsqcup_iA_i}\circ\kappa=T\kappa\circ\eta_{\bigsqcup_iA_i}$. Thus the right-hand side simplifies to $\phi\circ\mu_{\bigsqcup_iA_i}\circ T\eta_{\bigsqcup_iA_i}\circ\kappa\circ k_i$.

We now have that cocones $f_i\colon A_i\to A$ of $T$-algebra homomorphisms correspond naturally to $T$-algbera homorphisms $\phi\colon T\bigsqcup_i A_i\to A$ satisfying $\phi\circ\bigsqcup_i\alpha_i\circ\eta_{\bigsqcup_iTA_i}\circ k_i=\phi\circ\mu_{\bigsqcup_iA_i}\circ T\kappa\circ\eta_{\bigsqcup_iTA_i}\circ k_i$ for all $i$.

Since $k_i\colon TA_i\to\bigsqcup_iTA_i$ is a univeral cocone, this is equivalent to $\phi\circ\bigsqcup_i\alpha_i\circ\eta_{\bigsqcup_iTA_i}=\phi\circ\mu_{\bigsqcup_iA_i}\circ T\kappa\circ\eta_{\bigsqcup_iTA_i}$.

Moreover, the universal property of the unit $\eta_{\bigsqcup_iA_i}\colon\bigsqcup_i A_i\to T\bigsqcup_i A_i$ implies the condition is equivalent to the equation $\phi\circ\bigsqcup_i\alpha_i\circ=\phi\circ\mu_{\bigsqcup_iA_i}\circ T\kappa$ in the category of $T$-algebra homomorphisms. This is then the desired natural bijection between cocones under the discrete diagram and cocones under the parallel pair of morphisms.