# Coproducts in Eilenberg–Moore categories

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, monads

In [Category Theory In Context](https://math.jhu.edu/%7Eeriehl/context.pdf), Proposition 5.6.11 Riehl says that for objects $(A_1,\alpha_1)$ and $(A_2,\alpha_2)$ in the Eilenberg–Moore category of monad $\mathcal{C} \xrightarrow{T} \mathcal{C}$ (for cocomplete $\mathcal{C}$) we have that the coproduct $(A,\alpha)$ of $(A_1,\alpha_1)$ and $(A_2,\alpha_2)$ equals the coequalizer of
$$(T(TA_1 + TA_2),\mu_{TA_1 + TA_2}) \xrightarrow{T(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2)} (T(A_1 + A_2),\mu_{A_1+A_2})$$
and
$$(T(TA_1 + TA_2),\mu_{TA_1 + TA_2}) \xrightarrow{T(\kappa)} (T^2(A_1+A_2),\mu_{T(A_1+A_2)}) \xrightarrow{\mu_{A_1+A_2}} (T(A_1 + A_2),\mu_{A_1+A_2})$$
where $T(A_1)+T(A_2) \xrightarrow{\kappa = [Ti_1,Ti_2]} T(A_1+A_2).$
My question is, how do I define the injection morphism from $(A_1,\alpha_1)$ into $(A,\alpha)$ that we should have if $(A,\alpha)$ is a coproduct?

An extra thing I’m wondering about (in case someone wants to help) is that if I have $(A_1,\alpha_1) \xrightarrow{f_1} (B,\beta)$ and $(A_2,\alpha_2) \xrightarrow{f_2} (B,\beta)$ what is the corresponding [copairing](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/copairing) $(A,\alpha) \xrightarrow{[f_1,f_2]} (B,\beta)$?

Comment: Doesn't Riehl prove the proposition, or is it left to the reader?

Comment: These parts are left to the reader

Comment: I wonder if it would work to take the morphism $A_1 \overset{i_1}{\rightarrow} A_1 + A_2 \overset{\eta_{A_1 + A_2}}{\longrightarrow} T(A_1 + A_2)$ and then compose with the map from the coequalizer diagram from $T(A_1 + A_2)$ to the coequalizer.

Comment: And for the copairing, using the universal property of the coequalizer, I might try something like taking the map $T(A_1 + A_2) \to B$ gotten by composing $T([f_1, f_2]) : T(A_1 + A_2) \to T(B)$ and then composing with $\beta$, and then seeing if that has equal compositions with the two maps $T(TA_1 + TA_2) \to T(A_1 + A_2)$.

Comment: Fwiw I appreciated your videos, especially the one on adjoint functors, when I was first trying to study category theory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each choice of a $T$-algebra structure $\beta\colon TB\to B$ establishes a bijection between pairs of morphisms $f_i\colon A_i\to B$ and $T$-algebra homomorphisms $(T(A_1+A_2),\mu_{A_1+A_2})\to (B,\beta)$ given by the unique factorization of the copairing morphism $\left<f_1,f_2\right>\colon A_1+A_2\to B$ through the unit $A_1+A_2\to T(A_1+A_2)$ followed by a $T$-algebra homomorphism $\left\{f_1,f_2\right\}\colon T(A_1+A_2)\to B$.

One can then prove Riehl's Proposition 5.6.11. (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4549017/) by showing that this $T$-algebra homomorphism coequalizes the pair $T(\alpha_1+\alpha_2),\mu_{A_1+A_2}\circ T[Ti_1,Ti_2]\colon T(TA_1+TA_2)\to T(A_1+A_2)$ if and only if the $f_i\colon A_i\to B$ are $T$-algebra homomorphisms from $(A_i,\alpha_i)$ to $B$ .

This observation also answers both of your questions.

First, the coproduct $(A,\alpha)$ of the $T$-algebras has to be the coequalizer with coproduct inclusions of $T$-algebras the composites of the coproduct inlusions, unit, and coequalizer morphism: $A_i\to A_1+A_2\to T(A_1+A_2)\to A$.

Second, the copairing $T$-algebra homomorphism $[f_1,f_2]\colon A\to B$ is the unique factorization of the $T$-algebra homomorphism $\left\{f_1,f_2\right\}\colon T(A_1+A_2)\to B$ through the coequalizer $T(A_1+A_2)\to A$.