# Constructing coproducts from free products and coproducts in $Sets$

Tags: category-theory

One can check that the coproduct of $G=\langle A \mid R \rangle$ and $G'=\langle A' \mid R'  \rangle$ is $G * G'= \langle A \amalg A' \mid R \amalg R' \rangle$. I'm wondering if such an argument can be generalized for arbitrary categories $C$ with a right adjoint forgetful functor to $Sets$.

More concretely, given $G,G' \in C$, with $R:F(A) \to G$ and $R':F(A') \to G'$ the canonical maps of the adjuction, if there's a coproduct $G * G'$ then there is a map $R * R' : F(A \amalg A')\cong FA \amalg FA' \to G* G'$ induced by the coproduct map $A \amalg A' \to G * G'$. I have two questions about this:

1. Can we somehow state that $G * G'$ is (isomorphic to) a quotient arising from $R*R'$? If not, what natural requirements could be added to the category $C$ so that this can be stated and proved?
2. Possibly with the assumptions added in the first question, can we prove that a coproduct exists? It should be induced somehow from $R$ and $R'$, but $R * R'$ is no longer available.

Comment: In total generality, no. There is no reason for $R:F(A)\to G$ (also what is $A$? The only canonical map would put $A=K(G)$ if $K$ is the right adjoint functor and the counit has no reason to express $G$ as a quotient of $F(A)$ somehow. I mean, you'd need more structure to even express what that means (have some kind of terminal zero object, have equalisers and coequalisers.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct thing to quotient in a general algebraic theory is a **congruence**. It is a subobject $R \hookrightarrow G \times G$, satisfying reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity. The quotient is simply the coequalizer of the two maps $R \rightrightarrows G$. *Exercise*: prove that congruences in the category of groups naturally corresponds to normal subgroups. This legitimizes our practice of quotienting by normal subgroups.

Of course, we don't need to ensure a monomorphism, since for example we can consider the presentation $⟨a, b \mid ab, ab⟩$ where the relation $ab = e$ is repeated. So we relax that and consider simply an object equipped with a map to $G \times G$.

Now we may state our question properly: given $R_1 \rightrightarrows G_1$ and $R_2 \rightrightarrows G_2$, is the coproduct of their coequalizers isomorphic to the coequalizers of their coproducts? This is simply an instance of [colimits commuting with colimits](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/limits+commute+with+limits). The existence is also guaranteed, i.e. the theorem proves the existence of one from the existence of the other.

Answer (score 1):

In total generality, no I don't think you can always get this. You can't always even get a presentation, nevermind a way to combine presentations. But in specificity, here is a canonical presentation of algebras over a monad as quotients of free algebras. Source: [Category theory in context](https://math.jhu.edu/%7Eeriehl/context.pdf). This is one algebraic form of "generators and relations".

Let $(T,\eta,\mu)$ be a monad over a category $\mathscr{C}$, and $(\varsigma;\alpha:T\varsigma\to\varsigma)$ a $T$-algebra. Then within the category of algebras $\mathscr{C}^T$ there is a coequaliser diagram: $$F(T\varsigma)\overset{T\varsigma}{\underset{\mu_\varsigma}{\rightrightarrows}}F(\varsigma)\twoheadrightarrow(\varsigma;\alpha)$$Where $F:\mathscr{C}\to\mathscr{C}^T$ is the free algebra functor. In the case of Abelian groups, this generalises the observation we can always present an Abelian group as a free quotient via some relations.

That this is a genuine coequaliser follows from one direction of the Barr-Beck theorem. It also means that if you're a category equipped with a monadic functor to some other category, then all of your objects have a canonical free presentation.

Now, we can [also compute coproducts](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4548181) of $T$-algebras via quotients of a free algebra assuming that $\mathscr{C}^T$ has all coequalisers and $\mathscr{C}$ is cocomplete: $$F(T\varsigma_1\sqcup T\varsigma_2)\rightrightarrows F(\varsigma_1\sqcup\varsigma_2)\twoheadrightarrow(\varsigma_1;\alpha_1)\sqcup(\varsigma_2;\alpha_2)$$The anonymous $\rightrightarrows$ are explained in the linked post (which looks like a question but is actually answered; I link the question just for full context).

So if you live around monads, or monadic categories over another category (e.g. compact Hausdorff spaces over sets) then you can sort of do what you want to do.